# Remove 'index.php' from URL with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been trying all sorts of solutions from this site and none seem to work. I'm currently hosting with hostgator. This is my current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home/user/php.ini
    <Files php.ini>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all

    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

This is in the root folder of my site. I have also tried adding a `?` after `index.php` and no luck. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is happening instead?  Are you visiting `/index.php?magic` and expecting a redirect to `/magic`?

Comment: Is your web host running an apache server :D ?

Comment: @TIM I have link on `www.mysite.com/post.php` that leads to `href='index.php'`, and that link takes me to `www.mysite.com/index.php` instead of `www.mysite.com`.... if that makes sense.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is the code you can use in your .htaccess (under DOCUMENT_ROOT) to remove index.php from URI:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What would need to change in these rules for a url like this `http://site.com/index.php/Page/Param1/Param2` because it seems like the whole url is getting cut off after the domain for me.

Comment: I would like in the address bar to look like `http://site.com/Page/Param1/Param2` even though PHP needs to recieve it as `http://site.com/index.php/Page/Param1/Param2`.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. Here is the link to my question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567652/how-do-you-remove-inex-php-from-a-url-using-mod-write-while-still-allowing-php`

Comment: I was going to edit the answer but I'm not 100% sure. I'm fairly certain you need a / between \s and (.*) since otherwise the rewrite ends up with a double slash. `^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(.*)/index\.php` either this, or removing the slash from before %1. Either solve the problem on my end. Just not sure about all types of servers.

Comment: Using your code, how do I strip or trim the `.php` or `.html` extension on existing pages? ...what if I don't want to go back and manually rename existing `<a href="domain.com/xyz.php">` tags that already include the extension(s)?

Comment: @MaggewDotCom: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28091526/548225 and if it doesn't work, post a new question.

Comment: Your code worked for me with a little change. I added a /. Turned RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L] to RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 7):

Symfony 2 has an excellent solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

This accomplishes the following:

- `RewriteBase` is not necessary (useful when the site is in a subdirectory beneath the web root)
- `index.php` is removed if present
- The request is routed to the correct `index.php` with the full query string from the original request

Note that the line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
```

is responsible for setting the `%{ENV:BASE}` variable for later on. Refer to [Apache documentation on `E|env` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e).

Comment: I don't believe it! A working "index.php"-remover! Such a simple-claimed-task, such difficult to achieve!

Comment: I just wanted to say that it's 2019 and this has worked for me always, without fail.

Comment: This solution appears to keep `p?=` in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and works fine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Exceptions

If your site’s system directory (/system/) has been renamed and is still accessible by URL, modify the RewriteCond line above:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/newdirectoryname/.* [NC]
```

If you are running EE from a sub-directory rather from the root of your domain (e.g. http://example.com/myeesite/ instead of http://example.com/), just remove the slash preceding index.php in the RewriteRule line above, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you are running EE from a sub-directory and it still doesn’t work after removing the slash, you may need to specify the sub-directory in your rewrite rule. For example, if your sub-folder is named testing, change:

```
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) testing/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

And change:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ testing/index.php/$1 [L]

If your host requires forcing query strings, try adding a question mark following index.php in the RewriteRule line above, like so:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove **index.php** from urls on **apache2.4** you can use the following rule :

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule !index\.php /index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L,END]
```

This will change the uri

```
/index.php/foobar
```

to

```
/foobar
```

This rule will return an internal server error for lower versions of apache as they don't support the **END** flag. Please see the anubhava's answer above that works almost on all versions.

Answer (score 1):

I've been compelled to join stack overflow.com today to comment here as the answer has solved a long term problem I've had with a Zend Framework website.  I've worked on the website around 3 1/2 years and during that time I discovered that it didn't handle index.php correctly and this causes webmaster tools to see duplicate titles etc.

I decided to search again today for a solution, one of many times attempted.

This is the one (the last answer shown above) that solves my problem.

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

As an example.  this is what it achieves for me.

http://www.domainname.co.uk/index.php/categories/url-name.html

becomes

http://www.domainname.co.uk/categories/url-name.html

Thank you to everyone who contributed to the original question as it lead to the answer and solution above.

Extra Note: I have other rewrite commands that handles the other aspects but those on their own didn't fix the index.php and the only time this has been fixed is by using.

```
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

I only hope it helps others whether its ExpressionEngine or Zend Framework, in the future.