# How do you remove index.php from a url using mod_write, while still allowing php to see the path with index.php in it?

Tags: mod-rewrite

For the past 3 days I have been playing around with Apache's mod_rewrite trying to get it to remove index.php from my url, while php still needs to see it in the path.

```
Essentially PHP needs to see this
http://example.com/index.php/Page/Param1/Param2

While the user needs to see this
http://example.com/Page/Param1/Param2
```

What I have right now is the following in an htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Which was taken from another page, and is close to what I need. However this seems to be cutting off everything after the `http://example.com/` part. How can I get mod_rewrite to show the user one thing and have php see something else?

Comment: Did you ever get this straightened out? I'm attempting to do the same, just haven't found a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the modified code you can use in your .htaccess (under DOCUMENT_ROOT) to remove index.php from URI:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^index\.php)^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php(/[^\s\?]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L]
```

Change R=302 to R=301 once you're satisfied that it is working fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

This rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Needs to look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /index\.php(.*)\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Also note that `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]` doesn't create a URI that looks like this `/index.php/Page/Param1/Param2`, it creates a query string that looks like this: `/index.php?Page/Param1/Param2`. Which isn't at all what you said PHP needs to see.

Comment: Sorry to bring up this old topic, but I just came back up to something I needed this on lol. You said at the bottom that what I had was wrong to get what I wanted. What do I need to change that part to?