# apache rewrite rule modify url if not exits

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to write apache rewrite rule for fallowing use case.

My use case is if url does not exists modify url.

e.x

`http://localhost/sign` does not exists redirect to `http://localhost/index.php/sign`

if `http://localhost/images/dummy.jpg` exists do nothing.

i.e if url exists do nothing else modify url and add index.php after domain name and fallowed by requested uri.

can any one help me achieving this.

Comment: Your question sounds like the typical `.htaccess mod_rewrite` question covered in basically any how-to…

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove 'index.php' from URL with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608366/remove-index-php-from-url-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /sign
```

[ErrorDocument Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#errordocument)