# rewrite/mask url address in php and html

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, url-rewriting

I have read a lot of posts on how to rewrite the urls but still I couldn't find a way to rewrite the following:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php
www.mysite.com/login.html
```

to appear only like:

```
www.mysite.com
```

Any idea?

Comment: .htaccess and apache mod-rewrite

Comment: Thank you. i just can't find the .htaccess file. do i have to create it?

Comment: Yes, just create a blank text file and rename it. Make sure to enable display of hidden files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it should be something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I suggest you look here [Remove 'index.php' from URL with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608366) for a more specific answer and [here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php//) for a tutorial

Comment: Thank you. i just can't find the .htaccess file. do i have to create it?