# remove .html extension from url

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm trying to remove the .html extension from url for my website by editing the .htaccess file under the web root(public_html) directory. My server is bluehost.

The problem is that I have previous settings in the .htaccess file already for the redirecting primary domain to a subdirectory purpose.

The script is below. Also with the script i found online for hiding the extension from url.(The script doesn't work) It will be really nice if someone can help me out with the problem. Thanks.

```
# Use PHP5.4 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php


# BlueHost.com 
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?qinglish.ca$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/qinglish_ca/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /qinglish_ca/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?qinglish.ca$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ qinglish_ca/index.html [L]

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: The .html extension still shows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of your last rule you will need these rules to remove `.html` extensions fro all URLs:

```
## hide .html extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.html to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Place them at same place where you have current rule to add `.html` extension.

Comment: Hi sorry with the script you provided everything works perfectly, however, i just found out that my other subdirectories pages under the same domain are now having linking issues. like the link from this page stopped working. [link](http://www.qinglish.ca/cn/#/portfolio), [link](http://www.qinglish.ca/cn/portfolio-item-02.html). Is there anyway to fix it? @anubhava

Comment: Hi i'm not sure if i placed it right or wrong, so please go to this [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2798477/temp/index.html) and let me know, thank you:)

Comment: No the picture in the link is all the rules i have, i deleted all the rest .htaccess file from the other subdirectory folders, kept only the one in the document root, but the problem stays.

Comment: But `http://www.qinglish.ca/cn/portfolio-item-02.html` is just loading fine now though it didn't remove `.html` extension. Can you check your `VirtualHost` config and check what is `DocumentRoot` set to.

Comment: Hi I looked up some virtual host videos and really didn't understand and figured out how to check the virtual host and the document root set to...

Comment: Oh that is part of your apache config. You can ask your server admin if you are on a shared hosting.

Comment: So i just ask my server admin(bluehost) what is my virtual host config and what is document root set to? how do i ask the question and what answer am i expecting to see? haha sorry I'm being so ignorant.

Comment: Hi anubhava. This definitely solved my problem. However, I had a conceptual question to your answer. How is the server able to first replace the url and then redirect internally without changing the url again? It definitely works, i'm just not understanding the logic! Thank you!

Comment: It is because of `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable which represents original request to Apache and it doesn't get overwritten after internal rewrites.