# Remove .pdf file extension from URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pdf, mod-rewrite

I have a PDF file on my server and I want the extension to be removed when accessed thorough the browser.

I have added a redirect on .htaccess like:

```
Rediect permenent /somedestination http://example.com/somefile.pdf
```

I have tried many of redirect rules but all of them is for hiding the .html, .php etc. extensions but I'm not able to remove the PDF extension.

I'm new to this .htaccess scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the purpose of hiding `.pdf` extension?

Answer (score 2):

The rewrite rules that "remove" the html, php, or any other extension will look the same except you simply replace the "html" or whatever with "pdf".

For example, look at this question: [remove .html extension from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082552/remove-html-extension-from-url)

Follow those steps, and take those rules and replace "html" with "pdf":

```
## hide .pdf extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.pdf to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.pdf[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.pdf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.pdf -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.pdf [L]
```

Answer (score -2):

Someone feel free to correct me, but I don't think its actually possible. Opening a PDF in browser is much the same as serving an image. Your browser is directly opening and interpreting the file.

That being said, I can think of exceptions. Imgur can serve animated .gif images but the URL will read .jpg, so there may be some way to mask it still.

A possible alternative would be to find something to display the PDF on a separate page that you generate a name for. A 'hack-y' method might be to try and use an iframe? But there may be js plugins you could use or something similar.

Comment: This certainly is possible. The file extension on the URL does not actually indicate the file type to the browser (don't confuse what looks like a file extension on the URL, with the file extension on the underlying file that is served).