# Remove .html extension from URL on subdomain files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, file-extension

I have a problem with my .htaccess file. I would like to remove .html file extension on files that are in **subdomain**, but I can't do it.

Let's say that my website is `david.xyz` and subdomain calls `sub (sub.david.xyz)`. This is my actual .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

*Note: This .htaccess file works with non-subdomain files perfect.*

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove .html extension from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082552/remove-html-extension-from-url)

Comment: @thickguru It don't works on me :-(

Answer (score 0):

Ohh... I solved my problem:

> If you want to create site `sub.david.xyz/some-web/`, you need to create in the root folder of your subdomain folder named `some-web` and then create `index.html` file in it. The "beautiful URL" will be created automatically.