# Can't remove .html extension from website page urls

Tags: html, .htaccess

Will try and be as concise as possible.
I have read posts and pages which suggest I can remove the .html from domain.com/page.html to domain.com/page by changing the .htaccess file.

It was suggested that I paste this code into the file (which I did through Bluehost's editor

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I host with bluehost, and up until now have used wordpress sites.
Am creating my first site with my own html pages and stylesheets etc.

As such there was a lot of other info in the .htaccess file :

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
# Changed PHP handler from application/x-httpd-php54 to application/x-httpd-phpbeta on Mon Dec 14 19:23:46 MST 2015.
AddHandler application/x-httpd-phpbeta .php



# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^/wp-content/endurance-page-cache/ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(wordpress_test_cookie|comment_author|wp\-postpass|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/endurance-page-cache/$1/_index.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/endurance-page-cache/$1/_index.html [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 weeks"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So I just pasted the rewrite lines at the end of this.
The file is in a public_html folder. I then have multiple folders for all my websites.

So what am I doing wrong why is this not working? I have checked with Bluehost, I am using an Apache server

Thanks a lot for your help!

**EDIT:**
Tried Adding this as suggested at the end of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

And got left with this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv0GJ.png

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

This should remove `.html` from your URLs. Make sure you **clear your cache** before testing this.

Comment: I tried that and posted the error I got above.
Thanks a lot for your quick response

Comment: Hi @Sam, remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` & `</IfModule>` from around it. That is not needed. Also please place at the top of your `.htaccess` and then refresh your cache.

Comment: If that still does not work, then check out this answer from @anubhava - it should help: [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082552/remove-html-extension-from-url)