# Codeigniter url set to another page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter but i dont know how to put link to another page. My controller filename is aboutus.php. I gave a link like

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('aboutus'); ?>">AboutUs</a>
```

My base url is

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/project/";
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

But above url not working. I write a url directly in browser and hit like
http://localhost/project/index.php/aboutus then its working fine. how to give a url? i am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base_url()` will echo:

```
http://localhost/project
```

where as `site_url()` will echo:

```
http://localhost/project/index.php
```

You want to get to `http://localhost/project/index.php/aboutus` but with `base_url()` you're only getting to `http://localhost/project/aboutus` which is giving you the error.

You can do two things,

this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/aboutus'); ?>">AboutUs</a>
```

which means adding the `index.php` before `aboutus`

or this:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('aboutus'); ?>">AboutUs</a>
```

which means changing `base_url()` to `site_url()`.

Make sure that you are loading the helper in the controller:

```
$this->load->helper(url);
```

Or in `application/config/autoload.php` go to the line which says:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array();
```

and do this:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

and it will be included in every controller you now have.

If you have short tags enabled you can write your `a` tag like this:

```
<a href="<?=site_url('aboutus');?>">About Us</a>
```

or if you have the `url` helper you can write it like this:

```
echo anchor('aboutus', 'About Us', 'title="About Us"');
```

Comment: how to avoid index.php in url?

Comment: @udhaya http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608366/remove-index-php-from-url-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try site_url() instead of base_url() so index.php will not be skipped

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('aboutus'); ?>">AboutUs</a>
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Also, make sure that url helper is loaded.

```
$this->load->helper('url'); //can also be done in config/autoload.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using CI functions base_url() and site_url()
you need to load [URL helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) either in autoload.php or in controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have short tags enabled in PHP you can also write it link that:

```
<a href="<?= site_url('controller_name/function_name') ?>">Link Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this .htaccess on your base folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If YOu still not get the result Please enable **mod_rewrite** in your apache server

Answer (score 0):

your Project URL is look like you didn't enabled php short tags. Thats not a problem. just try this code:

```
<a href="<?= site_url('index.php/project/aboutus') ?>">About Us</a>
```