# Hide index and rewriting URL parameters using htacess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I Hide index.php and rewriting URL parameters

```
http:example.com/www/index.php?page=admin&action=login
```

as

```
http:example.com/www/admin/login
```

I have hide index.php using the code mentioned below ([Helped from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608366/remove-index-php-from-url-with-htaccess)) which makes URL as:

```
http:example.com/www/?page=admin&action=login
```

My htaccess file code

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  # Turn mod_rewrite on
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

But I need like this:

```
http:example.com/www/admin/login
```

If any body knows, that will be a great help.Thank you

Comment: change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]` now you will be able to get request uri in `$_GET['rt']` like `$_GET['rt'] = www/admin/login/`, and then just explode it with `/` and use that

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules in `/www/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```