# I'm having troubles with index.php in my urls

Tags: php

Hello I have a main domain that have instabuilder setup on and when creating a page with instabuilding it creates it as "maindomain.com/pagename"

The problem I'm having is with my addon domain when I create a page with instabuilder it creates the link as addondomain.com/index.php/pagename Why is the index.php coming up, the link doesn't look nice.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you can use in your .htaccess (under DOCUMENT_ROOT) to remove index.php from URI:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

copy from

[Remove 'index.php' from URL with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608366/remove-index-php-from-url-with-htaccess)