# Where is to place a redirect code on index.html to point to root

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.html?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where is to place this code on my index.html sites?.I have my

> "www.text.com/index.html"

and i need to redirect to

> "www.text.com"

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `.htaccess` (plain text) file in the same folder as your `index.html` Note that there is no first part, just dot-htaccess.

The code in your question is typical htaccess script.

*Note that htaccess files only work for Apache webservers, which are the ones typically used on shared hosting systems like GoDaddy, HostGator, etc - and also on XAMPP, WAMP, MAMP, LAMP*

Answer (score 0):

In my first answer I did not check your htaccess code. I notice that this line was missing from top of the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

So, it would look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.html?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

If that doesn't work, try one of these:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

or

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Sources:

[htaccess remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)

[Remove 'index.php' from URL with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608366/remove-index-php-from-url-with-htaccess)

Comment: I am using html code..will this one works? RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /www.index\.html? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?www.index.html?$ /$1 [R=301,L]...?..i need to point to root rather than www.index.com/html..

Comment: Try it. Refresh your page and see what happens. If that doesn't do what you want, delete the `.htaccess` file and post another question with a more detailed request -- what you tried, and what happened, and what you need it to do. When you accept an answer *(by checkmarking an answer)* and open another question, you will have dozens of new people looking at the question trying to help. Just make sure that you use the correct tag ***(.htaccess)*** so that the experts in that area will notice your question. *Also, tell us what kind of system your web page is on so we know if .htaccess will work*

Comment: I've tried all  it doesn't work for me on my .htaccess file:(

Comment: What kind of system is your website hosted on? `htaccess` files do not work on Microsoft's `.asp / .aspx / .Net` hosts. However, most of the web is run on LAMP, which use `.htaccess` files. If on an Apache web server (very common with shared hosting), then I suggest asking a follow up question. On StackOverflow, you get points for each closed question (when you accept an answer) and the correct answer is also rewarded points - so tons of people are *trying* to answer questions. Every new question gets *dozens* of immediate views -- keep asking / checkmarking / asking again until solved.

Comment: My website is hosted on Godaddy. i tried all those answers above still not working.It will take longer to updates on google?or once i made a changes it will automatically updated?.For your code above i only replace the index.php to index.html