# Laravel - unable to find new page (404 error - not found)

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I´m looking for solution for my laravel project problem (laravel version: 6.5.2). I found a lot of similar questions, but no solution.

So, I have created new laravel project and then i put it on my hosting.

My FTP structure is:

```
 - www
 - AutsokolaIS
```

In www folder, I copied content of Public folder and in the AutoskolaIS other folders and files (app, bootstrap, config, etc.)

Everything was good, until I tried to create a new page linked to welcome page.

Link is mydomain.com/page. After click on this link, I get 404 error page. When I directly open the URL mydomain.com/index.php/page everything works.

I know it´s problem with .htaccess file, but I´m not able to edit .htaccess file in correct form.

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you

Comment: is you AutsokolaIS folder inside www? Or alongside?

Comment: No, it´s on same level

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35014499/3532758
This solution works for me always.

Answer (score 0):

By default the website will be load from public folder. If you want to remove public from your url,copy `.htaccess` file from public folder to root and replace the code with the following..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Comment: So you recommend me to change default folder (www) to Public folder of laravel project?

Comment: I don´t now if my webhosting provider permit this change. I will try to send email on support.

Comment: NO, www is the public folder in this scenario. Dont change public folder. OP has already set www as public folder so your solution is not for OP.

Comment: This will not affect any of your code and webhost provider.This will simply load index.php from public folder to the url..

Comment: @JitheshJose there is no "public" that needs to be removed here.

Comment: Yeah it will remove the `index.php` and public (if exist) from the url.